# In PHP how do i update values in an asssociative array and store the entire array?

Tags: php

Here's a code example:

```
  $array = array();

  $array['master']['slave'] = "foo";

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {

      if (preg_match('/slave/',$key2)) {

        $value[$key2] = "bar";
        print "$value[$key2] => $key2 => $value2\n";
      }
    }
  }

  print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
bar => slave => foo

Array

(

    [master] => Array

        (
            [slave] => foo
        )

)
```

Rather i would like to have the following as the final array:

```
Array
(

    [master] => Array

        (
            [slave] => bar
        )

)
```

What wrong am i doing here?

Thank you!

**Note:
Example2:**

```
$a= array('l1'=>array('l2'=>array('l3'=>array('l4'=>array('l5'=>'foo')))));

$a['l1']['l2']['l3']['l4']['l5'] = 'bar';

foreach ($a as $i => &$values) {
    foreach ( $values as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)){
            print_array($value,$key);
        }
    }
}

function print_array ($Array, $parent) {
  foreach ($Array as $i1 => &$values1) {
    if (is_array($values1)){
      foreach ($values1 as $key1 => &$value1) {
        if (is_array($value1)) {
          print_array($value1,$values1);
        }
        else {
          print "       $key1 => $value1\n";
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      if (preg_match('/l5/',$i1)) {
        $values1 = "foobar";
        print "       $i1 => $values1\n";
      }
    }
  }
}

print_r($a);
```

Output does not reflect 'foobar' in l5

Answer (score 2):

Because `foreach` operates on a copy of the array. Read the documentation about [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Note: Unless the array is **referenced**, `foreach` operates on a **copy** of the specified array and not the array itself. `foreach`  has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the `foreach` without resetting it.

So you should do

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {

    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
          //...
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Ok, I reviewed your code again:

1. Your code was not working as your loops never reach the array with key `l5`.
2. The code is highly inefficient. You make assumptions about the depth of the input array. E.g. your code cannot process the input array you provide (it should work if you omit one array).

**Solution:**

Make use of [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). This code works:

```
$a =array('l1'=>array('l2'=>array('l3'=>array('l4'=>array('l5'=>'foo')))));

function process(&$array, $needle) {
    foreach($array as $k => &$v) {
        if ($k == $needle) {
             $v = "boooooooooo";
             print "$k => $v\n";
        }
        if (is_array($v)) {
             process($v, $needle);
        }
    }
}   

process($a, $needle);
print_r($a);
```

Hope that helps.

Oh and please use other keys next time. I thought the whole time that the key was `15` (fifteen) and was wondering why my example was not working ;) (`15` looks not that different from `l5` at a glance).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on foreach, it helped. 

But options 1 and 2 gives me syntax error : 
"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&'" 
because of &$array and &$value (starting elements of foreach)

Comment: @amnesia-55: True, I updated my code. I was not sure what they mean with *unless the array is referenced* so I thought `&` has to come before the array but it is only before the value. **To you second example:** You again forgot to reference `$values1` and `$value1` in your `print_array` function in the `foreach` clause. And I think you have to reference `$value` too.

Comment: Felix, thanks this works with 2D. But can you take a look at my edited question? the one with $a as the array name and let me know what changes need to be made? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Felix: I changed the code as you asked, but still it doesn't do the job for me! I need this working desperately as its choking up other things. So please bare with my impatience :) Can you know please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices, but all stem from the same problem, which originates on this line

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
```

At this point in the code, `$value` *is not* a reference to 2nd dimension of arrays in your data structure.  To fix this, you have a couple options.

1) Force a reference

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
```

2) Use a "fully-qualified" expression to set the desired value

```
$array[$key][$key2] = 'bar';
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you help detect the error in foreach for the code below?

<?php
$a = array('l1'=>array('l2'=>array('l3'=>array('l4'=>array('l5'=>'foo')))));

foreach ($a as $i => &$values) { 
  foreach ( $values as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)){ print_array($value,$key); }
  }
}
function print_array ($Array, $parent) {
 foreach ($Array as $i1 => $values1) {
   if (is_array($values1)){ foreach ($values1 as $key1 => $value1) {
       if (preg_match('/l5/', $key1)) { 
$value1 = "boooooooooo"; continue;
       }
     }      
    }
  }
}
print_r($a);
?>

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value)
{
  if(isset($value['slave']))
    $value['slave'] = 'bar';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $value is a new variable